# Entity Framework: Query multiple tables/entities with the exact same table definition

Tags: c#, entity-framework, partitioning

I'm working with a vendor database (I can't make any changes to the schema) that partitions data monthly and has been doing so for several years.  I've mapped EF entities to the ~100 tables and they all query fine.  For these 100+ tables (in my code), there is a common base class that defines all of the properties.

I also have a class that defines start date, end date, and the DataContext DbSet property that correlates with that time period.  My hope was to iterate this collection and apply query criteria to each DbSet that matches the time period, and union the results.

I'm having trouble defining that entity though.  I'm using reflection on the DbContext entity to pull out the property.

```
var property = _myDbContext.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(_myDbContext);
```

Then I have the class that defines the periods and entity (this fails - can't cast.

```
private class MyClass
{
    public DbSet<BaseDbSetClass> MyDbSet { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

Below also fails, can't cast:

```
private class MyClass<T> where T : class, IBaseDbSetClass
{
    public DbSet<T> MyDbSet { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

Is this possible?  Or is there a better way to handle the manual partitioning in EF?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please add the full code so we understand what it is you are trying to do? All I can get out of your question is that you want to do something with DateTime what is common over all your tables. I think I can help you but I need more details.